# how to add Asterisks symbol in red color to the textformfiled in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[1]i am new to flutter,  how to add Asterisks symbol in red color and hint as a black color to the textformfiled in flutter please help me

[enter image description here]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwli2.png

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
  TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          label: Row(
                        children: [
                          RichText(
                            text: TextSpan(
                                text: 'FIRSTNAME',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  letterSpacing: 3,
                                    color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                children: [
                                  TextSpan(
                                      text: '*', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25,color: Colors.red,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
                                ]),
                          ),
                          // Text("First name"),
                          // Text("*", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
                        ],
                      )),
                    )
```

[RichText Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure where you want the asterisk to be, but in a `TextFormField` you can use the `decoration` parameter to pass an `InputDecoration`.

This allows you to pass a `labelText` and a `labelStyle` as well as a `hintText` and a `hintStyle` like so:

```
class FormFieldWithAsterisk extends StatelessWidget {
  const FormFieldWithAsterisk({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: "*",
          labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
          hintText: "type here...",
          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
    );
  }
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I need hint text color in black Color and Asterisks symbol in redColor.

Comment: hints work just the same way, e.g. using `hintText` and `hintStyle`

Comment: when i use hint style it was applying for text and symbol too . i need different colors for hint text and asterisks synbol.

Comment: Thanks for answer, actually, I need asterisk symbol beside the hint text.

Comment: Ah, you can style portions of text differently using the `RichText` widget. But in the `TextFormField` you can not pass a widget as hint, only text. I think the material design guidelines forbid you to use different colors for a hint.
So I'd suggest to either extend `FormField<String>` and implement the FormField by yourself or try to use the `prefixIcon` field where you can pass any widget.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I did not want to use `hintText` as it was displaying only when the control is in focus. I wanted the label to be followed by an `*`, but in red color. Luckly, everything is a `Widget` in flutter and we can leverage that. The trick is to provide a composite widget to the label property, which includes a left label (which contains the actual field label) and a right label (which contains the required indicator). Here is a general idea.

```
TextFormField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        label: Row(
            children: [
                Text("First name),
                Text("*", style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
      ],
    )),
),
```

I would strongly recommend extracting this into a custom widget and using it across the application in a consistent way.